# Disable MacBook Pro Touch Bar in Boot Camp

Tags: windows, bootcamp, touch-bar

I recently set up a new Boot Camp partition for Windows 10 on my early 2020 MacBook Pro, and want to know, is there anyway of disabling the Touch Bar within Windows 10? I have looked on the internet and don't see any option for this.

One way I have tried is going into Device Manager (in Windows 10) and removing the Touch Bar but that doesn't seem to work.